# move_uploaded_file() function does not save file

Tags: php

I want to upload file and and save its path to database.But this function is not uploading file in the destination folder.
Here is my code snippet.
I have tried all the things but unable to find mistake.

```
$target_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/userUploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir.basename($_FILES["attachmentFile"]["name"]);

//$Filename=basename( $_FILES['attachmentFile']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["attachmentFile"]["tmp_name"], $target_file))
{
  echo "hi";
}
else {
  echo "<pre />";
print_r($target_file);
}
exit;
```

Comment: Check your folder permission.

Comment: Did you get errors ?